# Unable to run string functions on pandas Series values

Tags: pandas

```
i am writing to filter some code from a dataframe.
students = [('jack',  34, 'Sydeny',    'Australia'),
            ('Riti',  30, 'Delhi',     'India'),
            ('Vikas', 31, 'Mumbai',    'India'),
            ('Neelu', 32, 'Bangalore', 'India'),
            ('John',  16, 'New York',   'US'),
            ('Mike',  17, 'las vegas',  'US')]

df = pd.DataFrame( students,
                   columns=['Name', 'Age', 'City', 'Country'],
                   index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
```

i am trying to filter records for which country starts with 'I'. When i try to run this

```
print(df.loc[lambda x:np.char.startswith(x['Country'],'I')])
```

it says

```
string operation on non-string array
```

Even tried converting the column to string with

```
df.astype({'Country':str})
```

pl update what is the mistake i am making

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str` accessor:

```
>>> df[df['Country'].str.startswith('I')]
    Name  Age       City Country
b   Riti   30      Delhi   India
c  Vikas   31     Mumbai   India
d  Neelu   32  Bangalore   India

# OR df[df['Country'].str[0] == 'I']
```

You can read [Testing for strings that match or contain a pattern](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html#testing-for-strings-that-match-or-contain-a-pattern) to know more.

**Update**

To fix your code, you have to convert `Country` Series to `list` or `array` with `string` or `unicode` dtype (not `object`)

```
>>> df[np.char.startswith(df['Country'].to_numpy(str), 'I')]
    Name  Age       City Country
b   Riti   30      Delhi   India
c  Vikas   31     Mumbai   India
d  Neelu   32  Bangalore   India
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you update why np.char.startswith is not working there.

Comment: I updated my answer. Can you check it please?